# Keep tables <td> alignment unchanged when <tbody> is made to display:block

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a theme for SMF and the tables are a real headache. I have an example html code like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <table class="table_list">
        <tbody class="header">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <h3>TESTING</h3>
                <td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody class="content">
            <tr class="window">
                <td class="as">
                    <a href="">12</a>
                <td>
                <td class="bs">
                    <a href="">23</a>
                <td>
                <td class="cs">
                    <a href="">34</a>
                <td>
                <td class="ds">
                    <a href="">45</a>
                <td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And it's CSS:

```
#wrapper {
width:500px;
margin:0 auto;
}
* 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
table.table_list {
    background:#16A085;
    width:100%;
}
tbody.header {background:#2980B9}
tbody.content {
    display:block;
}
td.as {background:#E74C3C}
td.bs {background:#8E44AD}
td.cs {background:#E74C3C}
td.ds {background:#8E44AD}
```

If you test the code, if  css is not changed to display:block, the td retains its cell position in the table. But if it's changed to block,  cells acts like inline element! I am very sure I as doing something wrong.

p.s. I need to make  to block to style it i.e. add rounded borders.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5FU6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to close your  tags.

Secondly, since you are changing the display type on the table body, which changes the way the browser calculatyes the cell widths, you could try setting the widths specifically:

```
tr {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    clear:left;
}
td {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Which tags are open?
I tried putting width:100%. No effect :(

Comment: All of the <TD> tags are open (there are no close tags). As you can see, I didn't just set the width to 100%, I set the TD with to 25% and the TR element to 100%, so the TD has something to calculate on.